# Pentaho Installation and running problems

Tags: pentaho

I have installed Pentaho-server-ce-9.0.0.0.423 on current MacOS; then running set-pentaho-env.sh and start-pentaho.sh from Terminal. The localhost port is 8080 and shows 'It works' but still can not access the user console.  
Therefore, I have to check the log files in the tomcat/logs folder. pentaho.log and catalina.log because the BA Server fails to launch.  
When I was using  
`sudo ./pentaho.log`   
the return is 'command not found'. 
While 
`sudo ./catalina.2020-07-28.log`  
then the following info may gives the clue of why I am fail to launch pentaho BA server.

(base) xdeMacBook-Pro:logs xhu$ sudo ./catalina.2020-07-28.log  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 1: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 2: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 3: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 4: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 5: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 6: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 7: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 8: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 9: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 10: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 11: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 12: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 13: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 14: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 15: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 16: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 17: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 18: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 19: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 20: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 21: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 22: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 23: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 24: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 25: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 26: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 27: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 28: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 29: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 30: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 31: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 32: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 33: 28-Jul-2020: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 34: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:: command not found  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 35: syntax error near unexpected token ('  
./catalina.2020-07-28.log: line 35: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)'  


**what is the reason why I can not read `pentaho.log` because I need to find the clue of fail launch BA server, and what does catalina.log present in this condition?**

Comment: why you are using sudo command for reading the file ?

Comment: Because the permission denied when I used ' ./ ' to run in terminal.

Comment: Strange that you are not able to read the file, i am not familiar with Mac OS but don't you have to open using vi editoror with cat command.